# NAs introduced by coercion whith a line code that some days before worked

Tags: r, type-conversion, nas

I am trying to convert a variable codified as factor to numeric. I have two variables that are equal in this way in the data base, for one of them the code that I tried works but for the other one all the values are converted to NAs and I don´t know why because till some days ago it worked too.

The database is called 'Visitas'

The variables are 'result' and 'dose' both of them contain numbers representing the result of a medical trial and the administered dose in mg.

The code I used is the next one:

```
Visitas[, 'result'] <- as.numeric(as.character(Visitas[, 'result']))
```

```
Visitas[, 'dose'] <- as.numeric(as.character(Visitas[, 'dose']))
```

I have to convert them first to character type in order to not get the number of the level of the factor, remember this is how it is codified when I import the database, and get the number itself.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: What code do you use to query your database, before you attempt the conversion?